# What is the main implementation idea behind sparse hash table?

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashtable, sparsehash

Why does Google sparsehash open-source library has two implementations: a dense hashtable and a sparse one?

Comment: I think i'm misunderstanding the question in the post.  Wouldn't sparse hashtables + dense hashtables == all hashtables?  And if so, then why is the library called "sparsehash"?

Comment: BTW: [documentation from Google Code](http://google-sparsehash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/implementation.html).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The dense hashtable is your ordinary textbook hashtable implementation.

The sparse hashtable stores only the elements that have actually been set, divided over a number of arrays. To quote from the [comments](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/source/browse/trunk/src/google/sparsetable#605) in the implementation of sparse tables:

```
// The idea is that a table with (logically) t buckets is divided
// into t/M *groups* of M buckets each.  (M is a constant set in
// GROUP_SIZE for efficiency.)  Each group is stored sparsely.
// Thus, inserting into the table causes some array to grow, which is
// slow but still constant time.  Lookup involves doing a
// logical-position-to-sparse-position lookup, which is also slow but
// constant time.  The larger M is, the slower these operations are
// but the less overhead (slightly).
```

To know which elements of the arrays are set, a sparse table includes a bitmap:

```
// To store the sparse array, we store a bitmap B, where B[i] = 1 iff
// bucket i is non-empty.  Then to look up bucket i we really look up
// array[# of 1s before i in B].  This is constant time for fixed M.
```

so that each element incurs an overhead of only 1 bit (in the limit).

Answer (score 3):

sparsehash are a memory-efficient way of mapping keys to values (1-2 bits per key). Bloom filters can give you even fewer bits per key, but they don't attach values to keys other than outside/probably-inside, which is slightly less than a bit of information.